# Swift issue with inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a `tableView` which has a custom `inputAccessoryView`, and I have `tableView.keyboardDismissMode` set to `.interactive`. I subclassed `UIView`, and I create this class as my custom `inputAccessoryView`.

There is a `textView` in the view, and I have it resize automatically until a certain number of lines is reached. This is my code for that:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let path = IndexPath(row: self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
    sendButton.frame.origin.y = self.frame.maxY - 5 - sendButton.frame.height
    return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: (textView.numberOfLines() < 10 ? textView.text.sizeForWidth(width: textView.frame.width, font: textView.font!).height : 254) + textView.frame.origin.y * 2)
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    placeholderLabel.isHidden = !textView.text.isEmpty
    if textView.numberOfLines() < 10 { // I defined numberOfLines() elsewhere
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    } else {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

The `.async {}` block is for scrolling to the bottom of the `tableView` again once the `inputAccessoryView` height increases.

My problem is that when I drag down on the `tableView` to hide the keyboard, the `tableView` runs the scrolling animation (the one in the `async` block) when I do not want it to scroll to the bottom. Here is [a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0sudzk99mvdyam/Movie%20Recording.mov?dl=0) of what is happening.

I have been struggling with getting this to work how I want for a couple days now. Could anyone please explain to me why it is not working like I want it to and how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Nothing to do with "visual constraints".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my own problem! Hooray!

To do this, I created a public value in the `ViewController` for if the `tableView` is currently being dragged/scrolled. I used the `UIScrollView` delegate methods to set if the `tableView` is currently being scrolled:

```
scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_:)
  and
scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:)
```

I then changed `intrinsicContentSize` to this:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    if viewController.isDragging == false && textView.isFirstResponder {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let path = IndexPath(row: self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1, section: 0)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
    sendButton.frame.origin.y = self.frame.maxY - 5 - sendButton.frame.height
    return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: (textView.numberOfLines() < 10 ? textView.text.sizeForWidth(width: textView.frame.width, font: textView.font!).height : 254) + textView.frame.origin.y * 2)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having trouble with expanding my custom inputAccessoryView to a certain limit. The pattern we want to achieve is similar to WhatsApp, iMessage, Skype, etc in their iOS apps. If you could provide any help or guidance to help me achieve this, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!